# Probability of Independent Events-Pumps

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this question:
Two pumps connected in parallel fail independently of one another on any given day. The probability that only the older pump will fail is 0.12, and the probability that only the newer pump will fail is 0.07. What is the probability that the pumping system will fail on any given day (which happens if both pumps fail)?

My first approach was to do 0.12 * 0.07, but that's not the correct answer.
I looked for similar questions, but I just don't understand their process.
Any help?

Comment: It is worth clarifying/confirming the meaning of the phrases... It is possible that "*the probability that only the older pump will fail*" is meant to be taken literally that the older pump fails *and the newer pump did not fail*.  If $A$ is the event the older pump fails and $B$ that the newer pump fails., perhaps instead of being given $P(A)=0.12$ and $P(B)=0.07$ that instead the problem is saying that $P(A\cap B^c) = 0.12$ and $P(A^c\cap B)=0.07$ from which we are tasked with finding $P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Of course, if that is the case, you wind up with $$P(A)-P(A)P(B) = 0.12 \\ P(B)-P(A)P(B) = 0.07$$ which implies $P(A) = P(B)+0.05$. Plugging that into the second equation gives $$[P(B)]^2-0.95P(B)+0.07 = 0 \\ P(B) \approx 0.081\text{ or }0.87$$ and then $$P(A) \approx 0.131\text{ or }0.92$$ For which the answers are either $P(A)P(B) \approx 0.011$ or $P(A)P(B) \approx 0.78$.